# Why is my JSON parse not returning ' / ' symbols?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I figured this would be something simple, but it's my first time creating my own JSON file and parse.  I have the object `game` and the property `game.path.`  The path will point to a file location, but for some reason the parse returns a string without the forward slashes.  What should I be doing differently?

JSON code:

```
{
  "games": [
    {
      "game_title": "Skyrim",
      "game_series_name": "The Elder Scrolls",
      "game_series_sequence": "5",
      "game_path": "",
      "game_still_path": "StartScreens/Skyrim/maxresdefault.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

JS parse:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('screens.json', function(data) {
    var output ='';
    for(var i in data.games){
      output+= '<div class="col-lg-2 game-item" ';
      output+= 'style="background-image:"' + data.games[i].game_still_path + '"';
      output+= ' data-game-title="' + data.games[i].game_title + '"';
      output+= ' data-game-series-name="' + data.games[i].game_series_name + '"';
      output+= ' data-game-series-sequence="' + data.games[i].game_series_sequence + '"';
      output+= ' data-game-path="' + data.games[i].game_path + '"></div>';
      output+= '</div>';
    }
    $("#games-row").append(output);
  });
});
```

Result in HTML:

```
<div id="games-row" class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2 game-item" style="background-image:" startscreens="" skyrim="" maxresdefault.jpg"="" data-game-title="Skyrim" data-game-series-name="The Elder Scrolls" data-game-series-sequence="5" data-game-path=""></div>
<div class="col-lg-2 game-item" style="background-image:" "="" data-game-title="Morrowind" data-game-series-name="The Elder Scrolls" data-game-series-sequence="3" data-game-path=""></div>
<div class="col-lg-2 game-item" style="background-image:" "="" data-game-title="Oblivion" data-game-series-name="The Elder Scrolls" data-game-series-sequence="4" data-game-path=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't see any forward slashes in your JSON?

Comment: @DanielA.White the &#47; is not a "/" ?

Comment: @Superdrac thats only a representation of it.

Comment: you need to encode the entities.

Comment: In JSON it isn't. It is in HTML (although why you use it rather than a literal / I have no idea). I can't see any reason why it might get lost, but I'd really look at using DOM to build your HTML instead of smashing strings together.

Comment: Dear lord y'all are quick.  I had posted one of my test cases by accident.  I've updated with the correct code.

Comment: It's not a problem with slashes but that the output is `style="background-image:"StartScreens/Skyrim/maxresdefault.jpg"` which is invalid and breaks the tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but you may want to wrap the path in a url(). I don't think that would work regardless without that.

Comment: @Juhana ty, this is correct.  I also have a syntax error caught by..

Comment: @JonBlack, you are correct too.  Ty both!  Slamming my head against the keyboard for no reason again.

Comment: This is why it's generally better to append elements directly to the DOM instead of building a HTML string by hand.